# Loading Windows Symbolics in OllyDbg

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I am using windows XP SP3 and OllyDbg. Also, I have installed windows symbols from this address:
`http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/packages/windowsxp/WindowsXP-KB936929-SP3-x86-symbols-full-ENU.exe`

Moreover, I set `C:\WINDOWS\Symbols` in `Debug -> select path for symbols` in Ollydbg.
But I have problems with seeing some comments in comment column of Ollydbg.
Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

Questions regarding OllyDbg can be asked directly to its inventor, Oleh Yuschuk (also known as Olly) at Ollydbg@t-online.de.

According to its website there's a forum specially for OllyDbg at http://ollydbg.win32asmcommunity.net but to me, watching YouTube\OllyDbg is the most usefull help for OllyDbg.

Be sure to download the latest version of OllyDbg. If that doesn't work, try older versions, because OllyDbg has been completely rewritten in v2.00

More specific to the comments problem: 
Comments change as it dissassembles the code and the data changes as the code continues.. (*)

It has been reported to the author on 2 june, 2010 that there were problems with comments by 3 people.

---

(*) This should be edited for a better explanation.